# Uploading UWP to windows store

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, windows-store

I am attempting to upload my UWP to the windows store. To do so, I am trying to create an App Package. I am following the steps described on the Microsoft Docs webpage (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/packaging-uwp-apps), but failing when I try to create the app package. The error I'm getting is:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: IrishRailTimetables, Configuration: Release x86 ------
1>  IrishRailTimetables -> C:\Users\c-raf\OneDrive\Documents\College Work\Year_3\Mobile App\IrishRailTimetables\IrishRailTimetables\bin\x86\Release\IrishRailTimetables.exe
1>LOGGERBASEDEXECTASK : ILC error ILC1104: The directory is not empty.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try to clean solution and empty bin and obj folder and then close vs and open your project again and rebuild again then try to create app package

Comment: Thanks Shubham Sahu, fixed my issue, emptying the folders worked like a charm

Comment: Gld it works....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some times visual studio process existing or previous debugging files ,so next time when you debug existing files is not updated with new changes or unknown to new changes.
**Error - Old debugging Files not updated with changes.
so you need to follow these steps-

1) Goto Build > Clean Solution and Close vs.

2) Empty "bin" , "obj" folder of project.

3) You Should also view in taskmanager for any running process of .vs and close it.

4) Then Reopen Your Project and Build it.